# Calling Super Class's method from sub class objective C

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I have a superclass and subclasses in the following format:

```
 ParentClass.h 

 @interface ParentClass : NSObject

-(ParentClass *)field:(NSArray *)fields;
@end

ParentClass.m
#import "ParentClass.h"

@implementation ParentClass

-(id)init{
      self = [super init];
      if (self == nil) {
        return self;
       }  
      return self;
}


-(ParentClass *)field:(NSArray *)fields{
  ParentClass *pc = [[ParentClass alloc] init];
   // code      
   return pc;

 }

@end

Subclass.h

@interface Subclass : ParentClass

-(Subclass *)field:(NSArray *)fields;

 @end



Subclass.m
#import "Subclass.h"

@implementation Subclass

-(id)init{
   self = [super init];
   if (self == nil) {
     return self;
   }  
   return self;
 }


-(Subclass *)field:(NSArray *)fields{

// code      
    return (Subclass *)[self field:fields];

}
@end
```

I guess the issue is here.

return (Subclass *)[self field:fields];

I'm not accessing the parent class method the way I should.  Can anyone tell what should be the right way instead?

What if i call this way?

-(Subclass *)subClassField:(NSArray *)fields{

```
return (Subclass *)[self field:fields];
```

}

and i replaced the 
      -(Subclass *)field:(NSArray *)fields;

with 
     -(Subclass *)subClassField:(NSArray *)fields;

Comment: What are you trying to do, or rather, why is the question. You currently have an infinite loop and very strange structure. Please explain your end goal.

Comment: I need to access the methods from the ParentClass to retrieve the data and type cast it to subclass inside the method declared in the subclass. //-(ParentClass *)field:(NSArray *)fields

Comment: You can only cast to the subclass if it's actually an instance of the subclass. And that doesn't tell us what you are actually trying to achieve, it just tells us what you think the approach you want to take is... Why do you want an existing instance to create a new instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having said that is pretty unclear what you're trying to achieve, I'll tell what's wrong. First of all isn't enough to cast a pointer to a base class pointer, to call the superclass method, you should call it this way:

```
return (Subclass*) [super field:fields];  // Still wrong
```

But you're break polymorphism, and as the method signature says, you're returning a `Subclass` object, and the user that calls this method expects to have a `Subclass` object, but at the first call of a method that is just implemented by the subclass, it crashes because you're returning an instance of the superclass. Maybe is enough for you to change the method signature to return a `ParentClass` pointer, but this makes the method useless, why overriding it? It isn't pretty clear what you're trying to do, and what's your logic path.

**Edit**

Having seen the code that you posted on Github, here the situation is pretty different. In the Java code,t he method `field` returns `this`, so no new object gets created, and the method is just used for side effects. The `add` method doesn't break polymorphism, because just the object reference is of the parent class type, but if executed on a subclass it returns the object itself (`this`), which is of the subclass type.

In Objective-C for these cases the `id` type is used, which is used to represent a whatever object pointer, to a whatever class. You could also use the `ParentClass` type, but I'll stick to conventions. Here's an indicative code:

```
@implementation ParentClass

@synthesize endpoint

- (id) add: (NSString*) endpoint fields: (NSArray*) fields
{
    <code>
    return self;  
}

- (id) field: (NSArray*) fields
{
    return [self add: self.endpoint fields: fields];  
}

@end

@implementation SubClass

- (id) field: (NSArray*) fields
{
    < Additional code >
    return [self add: self.endpoint fields: fields];
}


@end
```

Comment: I made some changes. Does that help? Im not overriding it but just doing a typecast

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan Now that you don't override the method, you still have to return a real Subclass object, and if you return [super field: fields] from subClassField: , it'll be still wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/Semantics3/semantics3-java/tree/master/src/com/semantics3/api I'm trying to create an objective C code similar to the java version here. Semantics3Request is the parentclass and other classes are subclasses. Wondering if here is a way to achieve this logic on objectiveC

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan Now it's clear, you should have posted the code from the beginning. In your case the field method doesn't create an object, but it just returns self. In Objective-C usually in these cases, the id type is used. Give a look to the edited answer.

Comment: Should I have to declare - (id) field: (NSArray*) fields; instance in the SubClass.h file?

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan Yes.

Answer (score 2):

First please note that this code

```
-(ParentClass *)field:(NSArray *)fields{
    ParentClass *pc = [[ParentClass alloc] init];
    // code      
    return pc;    
 }
```

Doesn't look right from the software design perspective. From what you posted it seems that `ParentClass` instances can create and return other instances of its own type from the field method. This doesn't look ok, but it could be fine depending on what your intentions are.

Consider making `ParentClass` and `FieldClass` different classes if that makes sense.

---

Regarding the subclass, the way of doing what you want would be this:

```
-(ParentClass *)field:(NSArray *)fields
{
   // code      
   return [super field:fields];
}
```

Note that I changed the returned type to be `(ParentClass *)`, and the `self` to `super`. You cannot return a `ParentClass` object in the place of a `SubClass` object (the latter could have extra data that former doesn't know about). Doing the opposite is valid (you can return a `Subclass` object when someone expects to receive an object of `ParentClass` type).

Comment: I made some changes. Does that help? Im not overriding it but just doing a typecast.